# Calls to Analytics API for Content Owner Reports Returns NULL

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

We have been using the YT Analytics API to get metrics by report type for months.   Things were working well until Feb. 28, 2018 when all of a sudden we got null on data section and only the meta header.  This happened again today (March 2nd, 2018).   Please help.

(Updates)
Today is March 5, 2018, when "null on data section" is occurring again; although it was running fine on March 3 and 4, 2018.

Comment: Can you add any information on the error you have encountered?

Comment: Thank you for asking.
We run daily jobs on YT Analytics.   Most of the time
we get data & meta in the payload; from time to time 
we get only meta in the payload, with NO DATA like so:

  {
    "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
    "columnHeaders": [
      {
        "name": "day",
        "columnType": "DIMENSION",
        "dataType": "STRING"
      },
      ...
      ...
      {
        "name": "cpm",
        "columnType": "METRIC",
        "dataType": "FLOAT"
      }
    ]
  }